# How can I fix an element at the screen in react native. Something like a position fixed in css

Tags: expo

Because there's no position fixed in react native:

Invariant Violation: Invalid prop `position` of value `fixed` supplied to `StyleSheet input`, expected one of ["absolute","relative"].
StyleSheet input: {
"position": "fixed",
"top": 465,
"height": 40,
"width": 300,
"borderWidth": 1,
"paddingHorizontal": 20,
"margin": 5,
"borderRadius": 20
}

Answer (score 0):

in react native, you can use

Position:'absolute',
left:0,
top:0,

remember position absolute is limited to its parent view

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to refer that the element move when the screen scrolls so I want to fix it because of this. In absolute position it scrolls with the screen